# Facebook Messages sent VIA Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are Facebook messages sent from an external website to one's Facebook friends visible in the sending user's "sent messages"?

For example:  My website has an interface with a user multi select.  The user selects friends to which a standard message will be sent.

Once this standard message is sent to their selected friends via Facebook API on my website will those messages be visible in the sending user's "sent messages"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re sending the message using Facebook’s *Send* dialog, then yes, they show up in the user’s *sent messages* folder.

Comment: WHat if tbe message being sent is pre-fabricated, and there is no "Send" dialog in use?

Comment: I guess CBroe could rephrase his answer as 'if you're sending a message using Facebook's messages product, it will show up in that user's list of messages'

Comment: _“WHat if […]”_ – then you will please give a _detailed_ explanation of what you’re doing & how …